# Can order statistics be a random samples?

Tags: order-statistics

We can say a random sample means that  $ X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n $ are iid from a same distribution. But Can we use a same analogue to order statistics? I mean, Can we convert  $ X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n $ to order statistics $ Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n $ without losing properties of random sample?
As I write this question, it is get in my head that because order statistics are relevant to each other, So they never be a random sample. Is that right? Could you explain more sophisticated answer to me?

Comment: What is your definition of "random sample"?

Comment: I mean a random sample is a bunch of variables that are iid.

Comment: @MinhoKang After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

If by "random sample" you mean an iid collection of random variables, then no, the order statistics do not constitute a random sample. In particular, the order statistics are not identical because you are guaranteed that $$Y_1 \leq Y_2 \leq \ldots \leq Y_n$$

Moreover, if you assume that the $X_i$'s admit densities, then you can argue that the $Y_i$'s are not independent by observing that their joint densities do not factor into the product of their marginal densities (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795949/joint-density-of-order-statistics?rq=1)).